# Remove 1.js.map from git changes on Ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, git, typescript, ionic3

How to remove `js.map` files from `git` changes? I have tried many. But no luck yet. My project is `Ionic 3` app.

*.gitignore*

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
*.map
*.js.map
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.vscode/
npm-debug.log*

.idea/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
hooks/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
www/
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
.sourcemaps/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Commit all your changes
2. Use `git rm -r --cached .sourcemaps/` to untrack the index
3. Commit your changes `git push`

I hope it helps